# Is there any way to change http default value on URL Fields?

Tags: apex, force.com, fields

Quick question,

When you add for example an URL like "www.twitter.com/google" on url field on salesforce you will get automatically a URL composed as follow:

Auto Result: http://www.twitter.com/google

> My question is if there is a way to put HTTPS instead HTTP on that
>   function.

if I put : www.test.com then the field looks like : http://www.test.com instead of https://www.test.com

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a workflow to append https:// automatically.

Comment: To expand upon this answer, if you created a WF rule that checked if the prefix was not "https://", you could write a field update that pre-pended https:// to any URL that didn't have a protocol, or if it was http:// you could do a find/replace. You'd want to double check any other cases though, like ftp:// or anything else.

Comment: The problem is that the REAL value of the URL Field is just: www.test.com not http://ww.test.com so I Can't substitute on formula FIELDS.

Comment: But, you can create a workflow to override the incoming value if the value doesn't contain "https://"